# Making a bootable usb drive from Ubuntu

Tags: boot, usb

I had tried to make a **bootable USB** drive but it's not possible. I tried to do this by using *terminal* and also I used ***`startup disk creator`*** in Ubuntu but it always says that there is ***no free space in flash storage***.

Could you help me?

Comment: **no free space in flash storage** !! you should format ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open terminal by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> Then type

```
sudo su
```

It asks for your password. Give it and press <kbd>enter</kbd>

Then type `df`

The screen outputs directory path of all available drives along with their names in the form of `/dev/sda`, `/dev/sdb`, `/dev/sdc` and so on. Try to identify your usb drive number by compaing with the storage capacity of displayed drives. Note down the number and this number is extremely important. Let us assume it is `/dev/sdX`.

Now type in terminal

```
umount /dev/sdX1 

mkfs.vfat -L 'your-pendrive-label'  /dev/sdX1
```

Here replace `your-pendrive-label` with the label you want to give.

Explanation:

Pendrive cannot be formatted as long as it is ounted, we have to first unmount it.

```
umount /dev/sdX1
```

`mkfs` is apowerful command used to create or format file systems

`vfat` is an universal file system of pendrive understandable by all operating systems. It is actually `fat32`

`-L` argument is given to provide label to the new file system

and `/dev/sdX1` is the partition where the file system to be formatted is present

General **Syntax** of `mkfs` command is:

```
mkfs.<filetype> -L <label>  <partition path>
```

Comment: @FSh: If this answer was helpful to you, then please consider marking it as the [accepted answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) so others may more easily find it in the future. This is also a polite way to thank the person answering your question for helping you out.